# Stata: outreg2 multiple regression results with t-value, p-value

Tags: export, stata, p-value

I am trying to export my regression results to excel with the command `outreg2`:

```
reg index_bhar adsue1 i.date, cluster(company_id)
outreg2 using stock_regression.csv, replace bdec(4) sdec(4) ctitle(DSUE1) addstat(Adjusted R-squared, e(r2_a)) keep(adsue1) addtext(Time FE, YES)
```

How can I add the t-value and p-value of the regression results in Stata, in other words which e-class do I have to use?

Comment: Check `help outreg2`. The `stats()` option allows you to specify t values, p values and more options.

Comment: Dear Aspen, thank you for your answer, but isn´t stats() used for descriptive statistics? I need the result for estimates.

Comment: It works for estimates. Try adding this option: `stats(coef se tstat pval)` and click on the `seeout` link.

Comment: Dear Aspen, it works as pointed out. Thank you!

Comment: Statistical correctness: What you are doing is better described as multiple regression. Multivariate regression entails a multivariate response.

Comment: Dear Nick, thank you, you are right, the excample I posted is "just" a multiple regression rather than a multivariate regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the t-stat and p-value and then feed into `outreg2`:

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto
regress price mpg foreign

local tstat = _b[foreign]/_se[foreign]
local pval = 2*ttail(e(df_r),abs(`tstat'))

outreg2 using tptest.txt, replace addstat(t-stat, `tstat', p-val,`pval')
```

Read

Stata tip 53: Where did my p–values go?
by Maarten L. Buis.
The Stata Journal,
Volume 7 Number 4: pp. 584-586.
http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0137

As suggested there, you can also check `help estimates table`.

Comment: Sorry, but wouldn't this answer produce results for only one variable (in this case, foreign)?

Comment: @AspenChen Indeed. The code in the original question implies that only one variable is of interest: `adsue1`. But if that were not the case, then this should be a good starting point. Additionally, a reference is given in my answer that should lead the way to handle a more complicated scenario.

Comment: Dear Roberto, thank you for the code and the example how to -outreg2- statistics or values that is calculated on my own.

Comment: @eternity1 If you accept answers you like, both you and the person who answered will gain reputation. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Nick: Thank you for the explanation, a few days ago I tried, but had not enough reputation to vote up, but I did not notice the accept button.